Blazor EventCallback<T> from a SSR parent to an InteractiveServer Child Component is Null
I have a SSR Parent component with a Child component with InteractiveServer render mode. I need this child component to be interactive so that I can bind to events like @onclick etc. I want to pass data/value back to the parent using EventCallback but this delegate is never set I guess due to different render modes, is there another way to do this?
Parent.razor
<Child
  @rendermode="InteractiveServer"
  OnNameEntered="@DisplayName"/>

@code {
  
  public void DisplayName(string result) {
     Console.WriteLine($"Result is {result}");
  }
}

Child.razor
<input @bind="name"/>
<button type="button" @onclick="NameEntered">Click</button>

@code {
  [Parameter]
  public EventCallback<string> OnNameEntered { get; set; }

  private string name;
 
  public async Task NameEntered() {
    await OnNameEntered.InvokeAsync(name);
  }


I tried removing the InteractiveRender mode on the child and the delegate would properly pass to the child but then it would remove all interactivity within that component.

Your question would appear to be: "How do I implement Interactivity in a SSR component?"  I think you already know the answer: the parent needs to be interactive.

That's true. What I'm trying to do is the Parent component needs to display the currently logged-in user's email. However, with InteractiveServer render mode, calling the AuthenticationStateProvider in any of the lifecycle functions doesn't reliably give this information since the component lifecycles are being called twice. To keep it from running twice, I set pre-render to false, but AuthenticationStateProvider wouldn't return anything at all. So at this point the only thing reliable enough to display user claims is with a SSR Parent component.

So If I read this right, you're problem is with displaying information in the first  [pre-render] cycle.  Have you considered detecting the mode and acting appropriately, or turning off pre-render.  Here's a link to a question on displaying a splash screen during pre-render.

You coud try not use InteractiveServer, then using submit form to make button work in SSR. Try following:
Parent.razor
<Child NameChanged="DisplayName"/>
@code {
    public void DisplayName(string result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Result is {result}");
    }
}

Child.razor
<form method="post" @onsubmit="NameEntered" @formname="form1">
    <AntiforgeryToken />
    <InputText @bind-Value="name" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> NameChanged { get; set; }

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private string name { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized() => name ??= "";

    public async Task NameEntered() {
        await NameChanged.InvokeAsync(name);
    }
}

Test result

By the way, I think the better way is to make the authentication provider working on both Interactive and SSR.
